# Working with 2d array of class objects... VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

The following throws the following exception during debug
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Why?

```
Private Sub NewMazeGrid()
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer

    'Create Object (MazeCell) with four walls to start
    'See MazeCellInfo.vb

    'Create an 2d array with MazeCell object
    Dim MazeCell(nudX.Value, nudY.Value) As MazeCellInfo
    For X = 0 To nudX.Value - 1
        For Y = 0 To nudY.Value - 1
            With MazeCell(X, Y)
                .NorthWall = "Wall"
                .SouthWall = "Wall"
                .EastWall = "Wall"
                .WestWall = "Wall"
            End With
        Next
    Next

    lSample.Text = MazeCell(5, 5).EastWall
    'Return
End Sub
```

The goal is a 2d array of MazeCellInfo that contains four properties (n,s,e,w...) per grid square.

Comment: Looks like MazeCellInfo is a class and not a structure.  Fix with MazeCell(X, Y) = New MazeCellInfo

Comment: Everything i read you cannot do MazeCell(x,y) = NEW MazeCellInfo.  VB red underlines it when attempting  stating "Arrays cannot be declared with NEW"

Comment: let's try this question a different way.  I have four variables (N, S, E, W) that need to populate each square of a two-dimensional array (think of grid paper).  What is the best solution?  The above is using a class of four variables within an attempted 2d (X,Y) array.  The class contains Get, Set and New.  I cannot get past the .NullReferenceException when trying to populate the array.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got it.  Hans inadvertently gave me the answer.  Structure is the better solution over Class variables.  thank you.

Comment: Private Sub NewMazeGridStructure()
        Dim X As Integer
        Dim Y As Integer


        Dim MazeCell(10, 10) As MazeCellSt

        For X = 0 To nudX.Value - 1
            For Y = 0 To nudY.Value - 1
                With MazeCell(X, Y)
                    .NorthWall = "Wall"
                    .SouthWall = "Wall"
                    .EastWall = "Wall"
                    .WestWall = "Wall"
                End With
            Next
        Next

        lSample.Text = MazeCell(5, 5).EastWall

    End Sub

Comment: *"Structure is the better solution over Class variables"*. Nope. Using a structure specifically to avoid this issue is wrong. You should use a structure if a structure is appropriate and a class if a class is appropriate. The fact that you're using a 2D array is irrelevant to that. You're fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: *"Everything i read you cannot do MazeCell(x,y) = NEW MazeCellInfo."*. Nope. They're not talking about when you create the array. They're talking about inside the loop. You create the array and every element is `Nothing`. As you lop through the array, you need to create objects to assign to the elements before you can use those objects.

Comment: Okay.  Show me.  I understand what the problem was but every solution i came up with did not work because it was a 2d array.  In short though, the structure solution is quick, light, and painless, and handles exactly what i need it to do without all the overhead.  I was not even away of a structure solution prior to it being mentioned.  If you see a reason why the structure solution is lacking, please explain that as well.

Comment: `Structure` may very well make sense for your use case, just make sure you understand the behavior you're taking on if you use it.  In particular, I would strongly recommend to ensure that your `Structure` is immutable to avoid some behavior involving automatic copies that is very hard to reason about correctly.